# Unable to open Xcode 10.1. Getting Package Authoring Error

Tags: xcode10.1, xcode-command-line-tools

There are two Xcode 10.1 and 11 installed on my Mac wherein 10.1 is default one. I was able to open project using Xcode 10.1 until few hours ago. However, after restarting my mac I'm facing strange issue as described below:

```
Package Authoring Error: PackageInfo bundle reference found without top-level bundle definition. Bundle will be skipped.
```

Check attached screenshot for additional details. [image: Screenshot]

Below are solutions that I tried:

1. Tried mutiple time to open project using Xcode10.1 but still the same issue
2. Restart Mac.

Take a note that I cannot move my project into Xcode11 there are certain dependicies due to which I've to use Xcode10.1.

Comment: Jayprakash, this happened to me just now. Did you find any solution? I also have 11 installed but can't use it to do to dependencies.

Comment: @zztop : Check answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is enforcing developer to use latest version of Xcode.

There are two solution for this:

1. Move on to Xcode 11 (recommended)
2. Delete Xcode 10.1 and freshly install Xcode 10.1

I would suggest to **go with solution 1.**

Answer (score 0):

I have read somewhere answer but I am not able to get that link here,

but I know that you can try, change the system date to 3rd October 2019 and try again so it will work.

This is not my answer so all credit goes to unknown developer.